# not able to insert documents into collection using mongodb java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm using mongo mongo java driver version 2.11.2. I want to insert some few documents into my dbin mongodb and when I try to do it from command line it all works fine. But when I use mongo java driver, it is not working. I'm using `BasicDBObject` to populate the document. But `collection.insert(BasicDBObject).getN()` gives me 0 always. Nothing is getting inserted into the collection. Am I missing something here?

Adding the code:

```
mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("db");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
BasicDBObject o = new BasicDBObject();
o.put("key1", "value1");
o.put("key2", "value2");
collection.insert(o);
```

No update is made in DB after this.

Comment: need more details. Do you see any error?

Comment: Please post the result of getError() on the returned WriteResult.

Comment: getError() gives null.

Comment: Post the actual code that you're using

Comment: can u write your exact code, then it would be easier to troubleshoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'n' value from the getlasterror of an insert is always zero. (The 'n' value is what the WriteResult.getN() returns.)

See this MongoDB Jira ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4381. Which has been closed in preference to a new insert, update, remove mechanism: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9038

Long story short.  You are not mad or missing anything.  It is a "feature" of MongoDB that will hopefully finally be fixed with the 2.6 release.

Rob.

Edit:

I modified your example slightly to print the saved document.  Can you try running this version in your environment?

```java
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;

public class StackOverFlow {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost:27017");
        DB db = mongo.getDB("db");
        DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
        BasicDBObject o = new BasicDBObject();
        o.put("key1", "value1");
        o.put("key2", "value2");
        collection.insert(WriteConcern.SAFE, o);

        for (DBObject doc : collection.find()) {
            System.out.println(doc);
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine it outputs:

```js
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5235f98495302901eb70e7a4"} , "key1" : "value1" , "key2" : "value2"}
```

Comment: Whats the solution? How do I insert documents into collection from my java application?

Comment: If you are using a "SAFE" (or better) write concern and the insert call you have in the question did not throw an exception then the insert worked.  The WriteResult.getN() is always be zero.

Comment: I tried insert with SAFE and many other write concerns. None of them is working. I don't see any exception being raised. But my collection is still empty after running insert of multiple documents.

Comment: I think it was working so far without any issues. But surprisingly, on mongo console when I do db.db.collection.find() I always get empty result. db.db.collection.findOne() gives me null. Thats the reason I was thinking inserts are not happening. Any clue why it wouldnt show up on console?

Comment: Ah - I see.  Try "use db" and then just db.collection.findOne().  The db variable already points to the DB and doesn't need to be repeated. You were trying to use a collection named "db.collection" (which probably doesn't exist and the findOne() returned null.